# What are my options for setting user permissions with a CIFS share?

Tags: linux, mount, nas, samba, cifs

I have a NAS that only allows CIFS mounts on a Linux machine. I would like to set it up on a server, that I don't have root access to (but can ask every once in a while the root to do something on the machine) such that different users have access to different directories with different permissions. The ideal thing would be able to use the chown and chmod command, but this is not allowed with a CIFS mounting point.

Right now the NAS works fine on the Linux machine, only it is like the wild west: everybody has permission to look into everybody's else directories, even delete them if they wanted.

What are my options in regards to that with CIFS?

Comment: well, first, note that SAMBA/CIFS permissions stack on top of disk permissions, they don't replace them, so usually in windows anyway, you make your share permissions loose, and your disk permissions tight. In linux you have to do the opposite, and set the disk permissions to be loose (using chmod/chown) and your share permissions to be tight (eg bob can write; jane can read, etc). Most of this configuration is done in the `smb.conf` file, so become familiar with it, to learn about all the differant options. https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html